# Will a differential equation always have a solution if complex number is also considered?

Tags: calculus

> Will a differential equation always have a solution if complex number is also considered?

My teacher said that it does not have a solution always. I am new to this chapter and am stuck at this. Even more if we consider complex number what would be its geometric interpretation?

Comment: Not having a solution may have many causes. For a dimension-related cause cf [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/continuous-differential-equation-with-no-solution/). - In other words, the main question is: "What *is* a differential equation for you?"

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about functions of a complex variable, then only analytic functions have derivatives.  Thus e.g. the differential equation $\dfrac{dy}{dz} = |z|$ has no solution because $|z|$ is not analytic.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = 0$ when $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 1$ when $x$ is irrational there will be no function $y$ such that $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ is real analytic in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ then the IVP
$$y'=f(x,y), \qquad y(0)=0\tag{1}$$
has a unique solution
$$x\mapsto y(x)\qquad(-h<x<h)$$
for a suitable $h>0$. This solution is again real analytic, i.e., can be written as a convergent Taylor series
$$y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k\qquad(-h'<x<h')\ ,\tag{2}$$
whereby the coefficients $a_k$ can be computed recursively from the (bivariate) Taylor coefficients of $f$. Now the expansion $(2)$ converges not only for $-h'<x<h'$, but even for complex $x$ satisfying $|x|<h$. It follows that $(1)$ defines a function
$$\phi:\quad D_h\to{\mathbb C},\qquad x\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$$ that solves  the given IVP $(1)$ not only "formally" but in the sense of analytic functions and their analytic derivatives.

An example: The ODE $y'=1+y^2$ is solved by the function $x\mapsto\tan x$ which is analytic in the disk $D_{\pi/2}$ around the origin.